# Como monitorar mudanças em uma pasta?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso fazer para monitorar e capturar mudanças em pastas e arquivos?
Pretendo usar isso como parte de um serviço que se inicia com o sistema o script seria em `.pyw`.
exemplo:

```
if(mudou != padrao):
    pass
```

porem não sei como faria para esse script monitorar as mudanças dessa pasta, pensei em fazer com o `sleep()` porem não sei se haveria um modulo propio para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [Watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog)

Instale:

```
> pip install watchdog
```

Exemplo:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print 'Evento', event.event_type,' caminho:', event.src_path, 'diretorio?', event.is_directory

path = 'C:\\caminho\\desejado\\aqui'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```